# About the combination of include/remove words using str_detect

Tags: r

Hi How can we combine detect some words to include and remove?

```
library(magrittr)
data<-data.frame(name=c("john A", "john B", "john C","John A"))
data%<>%mutate(john_AB=case_when(
str_detect(name,"john|John")~ 1,
TRUE ~ 0))
```

In this case, I would like to code "john C" as 0, not 1.....

Comment: How about add condition `& !str_detect(name, "C")` in `str_detect...` line? Like `data%>%mutate(john_AB=case_when(
  str_detect(name,"john|John") & !str_detect(name, "C")~ 1,
  TRUE ~ 0))`

Comment: Thank you so much!. I should have coded like what you have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(name=c("john A", "john B", "john C","John A", "Tim C"))
data %>% mutate(john_AB = if_else((str_detect(tolower(name), "john") &
                                     !str_detect(tolower(name), "c")),
                                  1,  # true
                                  0 # false 
                                  ))

   name john_AB
1 john A       1
2 john B       1
3 john C       0
4 John A       1
5  Tim C       0
```